# Combining unit and property-based tests in pytest and Hypothesis

Tags: python, pytest, python-hypothesis

I need to run a mixture of unit tests and property-based tests in Python.  My current test code runs them separately, and thus duplicates some code:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("values", list_of_values)
def test_my_function(a_value):
    call_test(a_value)

@given(st.arbitrary_values())
def test_hypothesis_my_function(a_value):
    call_test(a_value)
```

There's a code repetition above: `test_my_function` and `test_hypothesis_my_function` are the same, just triggered by unit and property-based infrastructure respectively.

I would prefer to eliminate the code repetition above to obtain something like this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("values", list_of_values)
@given(st.arbitrary_values())
def test_my_function(a_value):
    call_test(a_value)
```

Can this effect be attained?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the latter? What happened?

Comment: Good question, thank you.  pytest complains that `test_my_function: function uses no argument 'values'`.  This also happens if I swaap the @pytest and @given calls.

Comment: Please add imports and some sample code for `call_test` so the code is runnable. I tried importing `import hypothesis.strategies as st`, but just got AttributeError for missing `arbitrary_values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your parameter list is a literal in the source code you can [translate that to a sequence of `@example()` decorators](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reproducing.html#providing-explicit-examples):

```
@given(text())
@example("Hello world")
@example(x="Some very long string")
def test_some_code(x):
    pass
```

If it's an explicit list you can write a helper function to apply them for you:

```
def parametrize(list_of_args):
    def inner(f):
        for a in list_of_kwargs:
            f = hypothesis.example(*a)(f)
        return f
    return inner

@parametrize(list_of_args_tuples)
@given(text())
def test_some_code(x):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you Zac.  The helper function was very helpful.